# Can the Breville / Sage Oracle grind and brew simultaneously?

Tags: espresso-machine, grinder, specific-machine

The Breville / Sage Oracle has a grinder, steam wand and espresso maker (not sure if there is a more technical term for the part where you click the portafilter into) in one machine. Online advertisements show it can steam and brew at once because of the double boiler.

I am more interest in brewing a few shots in succession*. Can this machine grind and brew at the same time? I'm assuming one has two portafilters at hand.

<sub>*I know the grinder heating up may cause the grind size to change.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is capable of doing this, but the machine only comes with one porta filter.

In fact, my Barista Express is capable of grinding while brewing, but again only 1 porta filter. You would need to buy a second one to do both.